# Low- Drift Voltage

Tags: voltage, adc, i2c

When I go through the datasheet of external ADC module ADS1115, I have come across a word 'Low-drift Voltage'. What is it and how should I consider this feature when designing a circuit?
Here is the [link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf) for the datasheet of ADC module. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Low drift? the ADC will need little or no recalibration over the lifetime of its use. In other words, the Zero point and the FullScale point will be rather stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read one more word along, the datasheet advertises a "low-drift voltage reference".

A *voltage reference* is a circuit that produces a fixed output voltage to be used as a reference for some other circuit (for example, for the ADC to compare the input voltage to, to determine what its output should be).

A low-drift voltage reference is one that doesn't change very much over time. Usually this is caused by temperature changes on the chip. It's important the reference voltage doesn't change much, because any change in the reference voltage will cause changes in the ADC output value.